# How could a Docker container get host process quit message?

Tags: docker

We have two processes in our project, and they run in the physical machine as two Systemd services with a 'BindsTo' config. If process A is restarted, process B would restart too. They worked well until we have to containerize process B for some reasons. Now, process A runs in the host machine, while process B is inside a Docker container，and the Systemd mechanism doesn't work anymore.

Is there any way to for process B to get notified as soon as the process A restarts, just like what Systemd 'BindsTo' do?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your container in a systemd `Unit`, and you can control your container like a systemd `service`. For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=B in Docker
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStartpre=-/usr/bin/docker stop container_b
ExecStartpre=-/usr/bin/docker rm container_b
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name container_b image:tag
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop container_b
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker rm container_b
Restart=always
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, our containers are managed by k8s，this solution may be not suitable for us.